# tcl child process executed abnormally

Tags: process, tcl

I'm using the code here to run some processes in parallel.

https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Execute+in+Parallel+and+Wait

Here is the code that I've modified.

```
foreach scenario $scenario_list {
    set script {            
        set sname $scenario
        puts "Scenario: $sname"          
        set sdir "$curr_dir/$sname"
        puts "Results from: $sdir"
        extract_system_kpis $sname "SUCCESS" $sdir $hw_instance_list $hbm_scheduler_pairs
    }
    set chan [open |[list [info nameofexecutable] <<$script 2>@stderr]] 
    dict set res $chan command $script
    fconfigure $chan -blocking 0
    lappend background $chan
}

while 1 {
    foreach chan $background {
        if {[eof $chan]} {
            fconfigure $chan -blocking 1
            if {[set idx [lsearch -exact $background $chan]] >= 0} {
                set background [lreplace $background $idx $idx]
            }
            catch [close $chan] cres copts
            dict set res $chan result $cres
            dict set res $chan options $copts
        } else {
            puts -nonewline [read $chan]
        }
    }
    if {[llength $background] == 0} {
        break
    }
    after 100
}
return $res
```

I'm getting the error
child process exited abnormally
while executing
"close $chan"

Any ideas? I'm running TCL 8.6

Thanks

Comment: That error means that the subprocess exit code (or at least one of them in a multi-stage pipeline) was non-zero. Because you've redirected stderr, you'll need to read wherever that went to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Also, if the subprocess just does `exit 1` without printing to `stderr` — you control the code that decides whether it will — then there's not much to see.

Comment: There are Java errors "Main class not found" while executing close $chan